# Adjust insets of a specific section in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewdelegate

1. insetForSectionAtIndex (on DelegateFlowLayout) enables one to set insets for all cells within a section
2. sectionInset (on FlowLayout) enables one to set insets that applies to all sections.

However, I am looking for a way of applying insets to only one specific section - is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must have to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your class with this method:

**For Swift 4, 5+**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    var edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets()
    if section == THE_SECTION_YOU_WANT {
        // edgeInsets configuration stuff
    }

    return edgeInsets;
}
```

**For Swift 3**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    var edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets()
    if section == THE_SECTION_YOU_WANT {
        // edgeInsets configuration stuff
    }

    return edgeInsets;

}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, and it seems to apply the inset to all elements in the section. Is there a way I can apply it to the entire section, not each element?

Comment: @GauravSharma This method apply the inset to the entire section, that's the reason it gives it an section `Int`.

Comment: just tried again - same result - it applies the insets to each cell in the section, rather than the section.

Comment: @GauravSharma and what is the difference? Do you want to apply the inset to the header section and footer section?

Comment: Nope, I want to inset the entire section (not each item in the section).

Comment: Actually that works fine - there was something else that made it look like it was not working. Putting a 100 pixel left/right inset works fine - if anyone else tries this and gets odd results, bear in mind the collection view applies automatic spacing which may make it look like inner cells are being inset!

Answer (score 1):

for swift 4 is named:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do something like this from the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        switch section {
        case 0:
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        case 1:
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        }
    }
```